# How to get the datetime value from combo box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datetime-format

I have filled a combo box with the variables of long datetime, In combo i have shown only the Month names....

I want to get the datetime value corresponding to the selected month in combo.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If itmes are just month string you can't restore full datetime. The best you can do is to parse month string and construct a new DateTime based on the parsed month and constant year, day and time, like this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dropDownList.SelectedItem.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

Replace `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` with the required culture if month name culture is different from UI culture.

Comment: `SelectedValue` is a string, you can't cast that to a `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

You've taged the question asp.net, so i guess its a web app.
Assuming the datetime value is in the `value` property and the month only in the `text` property of the `ListItem`

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```